# Select rows in dataframe based on a specific value in any column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, that contains e.g. 5 rows and 3 columns:

[image: dataframe]

I would like to select those rows, which contains for example text yellow (rows 1 and 4)?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to select rows that contain "yellow" in any column:

```
library(tidyverse)

result <- mydata %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(. == "yellow"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `subset` + `rowSums`

```
subset(df,rowSums(df=="yellow")>0)
```